# How can I switch two fields of a unique row within one commit using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

Assume to have a object with unique name. Now you want to switch the name of two objects:

Here is the layout:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MyObject(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'my_objects'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.Text, unique=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
  Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
  Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  session = Session()
```

And I would like to do this:

```
a = MyObject(name="Max")
b = MyObject(name="Moritz")
session.add_all([a, b])
session.commit()

# Now: switch names!
tmp = a.name
a.name = b.name
b.name = tmp
session.commit()
```

This throws an `IntegrityError`. Is there a way to switch these fields within one commit without this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave `unique=True` in the name field so when you are trying to commit it will run the update query it will raise the error.

The situation is when you change the name it will set in memory. But when it will try to run the update query the old record already exist with same name so it will give the `IntegrityError`.

The way to change name is

```
a = MyObject(name="Max")
b = MyObject(name="Moritz")
session.add_all([a, b])
session.commit()

# Now: switch names!
atmp = a.name
btemp = b.name

a.name = a.name+btemp # Temp set the any random name
session.commit()

b.name = atemp
a.name = btemp
session.commit() # Run the update query for update the record.
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it seems to be a basic SQL property that is passed directly through SQLAlchemy. Here is a link to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644/swap-unique-indexed-column-values-in-database

Comment: For some reason I also had to set `b.name` to a random value (besides `a.name`) because, in some cases, the second `session.commit()` was raising an IntegrityError.

Comment: The first commit should probably be a flush(), because otherwise you violate ACID semantics (your change is not atomic).

Answer (score 5):

A more pure option would be to delete a, rename b, then re-add a renamed:

```
session.delete(a)
sqlalchemy.orm.session.make_transient(a)
a.name, b.name = b.name, a.name
session.flush()
session.add(a)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python allows this syntax(using tuples):

```
a.name, b.name = b.name, a.name
```

It's absolutely okay to switch two normal arguments this way, but not tested in your situation, maybe you can give it a try?

Comment: As long as I don't commit to the database that works fine. The problem seems to be the database.

Comment: I don't seem to find a equivalent one-statement SQL to do this, too. Maybe this is something SQLAlchemy did not take into account.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Philipp der Rautenberg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109915/how-can-i-switch-two-fields-of-a-unique-row-within-one-commit-using-sqlalchemy/69330425#comment11449601_9110785) I found nicer solution which works with PostgreSQL, but not SQLite.

More information on how it works is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12437451/8896457) and in [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html) and in [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Constraint).

The idea is to first declare unique constraint as `deferrable` and then set it as `DEFERRED` either by using it in `initially`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MyObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_object'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Text)
    name_unique_constraint = sa.UniqueConstraint(name, deferrable=True, initially='DEFERRED')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name', echo=True)
    Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()

    a = MyObject(name="Max")
    b = MyObject(name="Moritz")
    session.add_all([a, b])
    session.commit()

    # Now: switch names!
    a.name, b.name = b.name, a.name

    session.add_all([a, b]) # this line seems to be necessary to raise exception if swap woudn't be possible
    session.commit()
```

or with explicit sql statement:

```
db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED')
```

or

```
db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS uq_my_object_name DEFERRED')
```

but remember when using `SET CONSTRAINTS` that:

> This command only alters the behavior of constraints within the current transaction.