# How do I switch two ID [PK] on postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to change the ID on two rows on Postgres, to switch them. They are already defined as foreign key so I cannot use a third number to do the switch.

How can I do this in one SQL query or transaction?

Example:

```
UPDATE mytable SET id=2 WHERE ID=1;
UPDATE mytable SET id=1 WHERE ID=2
```

Comment: When you have transactional integrity, you don't _need_ to do it on one line !!

Comment: Are you saying the records linked to id = 1 after the change need to stay linked to id = 1? ie you don't want to change the dependant tables?

Comment: instead of changing the ID's, could you use a solution where all of the other attributes are changed instead?

Comment: Closely related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/644/939860).

Comment: What about swapping contents instead of swapping identificators?

Answer (score 6):

You mention foreign keys, but it remains unclear whether `id` is the referenced or the referencing column of a foreign key constraint.

If **`id` is the referenced column** you just define the fk constraint [**`ON UPDATE CASCADE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html). Then you can change your `id` as much as you want. Changes are cascaded to the depending columns.

---

If **`id` is the referencing column** (and no other foreign key constraints point to it), then there is another, faster way since **PostgreSQL 9.0**. You can use a deferrable primary or unique key. Consider the following demo:

**Note** that you can't use this if you want to reference `id` with a **foreign key** constraint from another table. I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html):

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique
> or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

Testbed:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t
( id integer
 ,txt text
 ,CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1, 'one')
,(2, 'two');
```

Update:

```
UPDATE t
SET    id = t_old.id
FROM   t t_old
WHERE (t.id, t_old.id) IN ((1,2), (2,1));
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM t; 

id | txt
---+-----
2  | one
1  | two
```

You can also declare the constraint `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` and use `SET CONSTRAINTS ... DEFERRED` in the same transaction.

Be sure to read about the details in the manual:

- [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)
- [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set-constraints.html)

---

Even seems to work with `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` and no `SET CONSTRAINTS`. I posted a [question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860).

Comment: I understand that a referenced column can not be a column of a deferrable primary key. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: As I commented previously in an answer that has been deleted, this wouldn't do because as of the latest PG9.1 you can't have a FOREIGN KEY pointing to a unique column with a DEFERRABLE constraint, and the question specifically mentions the existence of the FK.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Yes, that's an important restriction about foreign keys. I added a note to my answer..

Comment: @DanielVérité: It is unclear from the question whether `id` is the referenced or the referencing column of a foreign key constraint. If it is the referencing column, this would work.

Comment: @Erwin: I wondered as well when reading the question, but since the title says "...ID [PK]...", I assumed mytable.ID is the primary key and some unmentioned table points to it. Maybe the author should clarify that.

Comment: @DanielVérité: Yeah, clarification is in order. I split my answer in two cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12437451/905902 Funny, it appears I created almost the same example data for a similar question / topic.

Comment: @wildplasser: Small world. :) And fitting answer over there.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin;
alter table mytable drop constraint_name;
UPDATE mytable SET id=-1 WHERE ID=1;
UPDATE mytable SET id=1 WHERE ID=2;
UPDATE mytable SET id=2 WHERE ID=-1;
alter table mytable add table_constraint;
commit;
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity, but only in case where the change is applied once... not suitable for a daily script to be run after any statement that modifies data

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE updates ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT column1::int oldid, column2::int newid
FROM ( VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1) ) foo;

UPDATE mytable
FROM updates
SET id = newid
WHERE id = oldid;

--COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;
```

Of course rollback gets commented out and commit in when you are ready to go.

Comment: You definetly missed something on the `UPDATE`.