# Is it possible to set a primary key to DEFERRABLE?

Tags: postgresql

my question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029691/how-do-i-switch-two-id-pk-on-postgres-database). 
I want to switch two id of a table which are defined as primary keys.

But unfortunately the table where I want to switch the ids was already created and the primary key constraint was not set do `deferrable`.

I tried to set it to deferrable with the following statement:
`alter table table_name alter constraint primary_key_name_pkey deferrable;`

And got an error:
`constraint "primary_key_name_pkey" of relation "table_name" is not a foreign key constraint`

Is there any way to set a primary key constraint to deferrable after creation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to drop and re-create the PK mark it as deferrables when you create it.

Comment: For a single pair of rows, a possible workaround *could* be to swap via a temp value. (this could affect triggers, etc, but changing a PK value is suspect anyway ...)

Comment: It seems that you cant defer a PK if there are foreign key contrsints referencing it. My workarround was a small python script that dropped all foreign key constraints and the PK itself, did the id swaps of the ids and then restored all constraints again.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the source code of PostgreSQL:

```
/*
 * ALTER TABLE ALTER CONSTRAINT
 *
 * Update the attributes of a constraint.
 *
 * Currently only works for Foreign Key constraints.
 * Foreign keys do not inherit, so we purposely ignore the
 * recursion bit here, but we keep the API the same for when
 * other constraint types are supported.
```

Source: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L9557

So, it's not possible, even with Pg12.