# The correct way to swap values that have a unique constraints with Ecto?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I need to swap values that have unique constraints. I'm trying to use the update_all function as shown below.

```
from(e in Episode, where: e.show_id == ^id, update: [set: [position: fragment("position + 1")]])
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

When using this I get an error because of a duplicate position:

```
ERROR (unique_violation): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "position_show_id_index"
table: episodes
constraint: position_show_id_index
Key ("position", show_id)=(2, 27) already exists.
```

How can I swap these position values simultaneously?

Comment: I think one way to go would be to just use a transaction and first check and maybe delete the previous record and then just insert a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no "nice" way to swap unique indexed values in SQL.

[Two known solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644/swap-unique-indexed-column-values-in-database) are **1)** deleting and reinserting the rows, or **2)** updating the rows to another placholder value before updating both of them.

You could take a similar approach in Ecto like this:

**Solution 1:**

```elixir
episode = Repo.get(Episode, id)
next_episode = Repo.get_by(Episode, position: episode.position + 1)

if next_episode, do: Repo.delete(next_episode)

episode
|> Episode.changeset(%{position: episode.position + 1})
|> Repo.update()

if next_episode do
  Repo.insert(%Episode{next_episode | position: episode.position})
end
```

**Solution 2:**
(You'll need to choose some "impossible" value as a placeholder. For example, if position must be positive, you can use a negative number)

```elixir
episode = Repo.get(Episode, id)
next_episode = Repo.get_by(Episode, position: episode.position + 1)

if next_episode do
  next_episode
  |> Episode.changeset(%{position: -1})
  |> Repo.update()
end

episode
|> Episode.changeset(%{position: episode.position + 1})
|> Repo.update()

if next_episode do
  next_episode
  |> Episode.changeset(%{position: episode.position})
  |> Repo.update()
end
```

The second solution might be preferable if you have any foreign key constraints referencing `Episode`.